# Put a key of end of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2016-03-08
        [value] => Array
            (
                [key_1] => Array
                    (
                        [test_1] => 1
                        [test_2] => 10
                        [test_3] => 1000
                        [test_4] => 200
                    )

                [key_2] => Array
                    (
                        [test_1] => 1
                        [test_2] => 15
                        [test_3] => 1500
                        [test_4] => 100
                    )

             )
)
```

Now I have another array :

```
Array
(
  [key_3] => Array
    (
        [test_1] =>
        [test_2] =>
        [test_3] =>
        [test_4] => 1
    )
```

)
I want to add this last array in the first array.
I try like this : `array_push($ymlParsedData[]['value'], $a_big_gift);` but not work. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code, we cannot help otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: It will be like this:  array_push($ymlParsedData[0]['value'], $a_big_gift);

Comment: for making it dynamic you need to loop the array and use array_push($ymlParsedData[$index]['value'], $a_big_gift);

Comment: How does the expected output looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$ymlParsedData[]` for accessing specific element, it is a shorthand for pushing data to array.

You can use either

```
// NB! array_push() just adds the values, key 'key_3' is removed
array_push($ymlParsedData[0]['value'], $a_big_gift);
```

or

```
// will keep key 'key_3'
$ymlParsedData[0]['value']['key_3'] = $a_big_gift['key_3'];
```

or

```
// use array_merge() instead
$ymlParsedData[0]['value'] = array_merge($ymlParsedData[0]['value'], $a_big_gift);
```

Answer (score 1):

A complicated answer, but this might solve your issue:

```
$key_name = array_keys($a_big_gift)[0];
$ymlParsedData[0]['value'][$key_name] = $a_big_gift[$key_name];

echo '<pre>'; print_r($ymlParsedData); exit;
```

Note: For making it dynamic and for more than one value of `$a_big_gift`, you need to loop it and achieve your result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array_push($ymlParsedData[0]['value'], $a_big_gift['key_3']);
```